# Trouble with Tufte-style bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am studying this article: "[Tufte-style Bar Charts with pgfplots](https://latex.net/tufte-bar-charts/)". I was able to come up to step #4, and was stuck, removing the border from the bars:

```
\definecolor{tufte1}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.55}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
  cycle list={
    fill=tufte1, draw=none\\
  }
...
```

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
%I added this
\definecolor{tufte1}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.55}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  hide x axis,
  axis line style={opacity=0},
  major tick style={draw=none},
  ymin=0,
  bar width=0.9em,
  ymajorgrids,
  major grid style=white,
  axis on top
]
%and this
cycle list={
    fill=tufte1, draw=none\\
}
\addplot table {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

data.csv:

```
1    8.5
2   12
3    6.5
4    7
5    3
6   17.5
7   13
8    8.5
9    6
10  11
11   5
12  10
```

But it doesn't work: the color is not changed, and the border stays intact:

[image]

How to remove the borders and change the color?

[image]

(I didn't narrow the bars - I don't like it).

Comment: Please add some example data to your MWE :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Added

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `cycle list` key has to be added to the `\begin{axis}[...]` options, so it has to be within the square brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{tufte1}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.55}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  hide x axis,
  axis line style={opacity=0},
  major tick style={draw=none},
  ymin=0,
  bar width=0.9em,
  ymajorgrids,
  major grid style=white,
  axis on top, % Don't close the square brackets here...
  cycle list={
    fill=tufte1, draw=none\\
  }
] % ... do it here
\addplot table {
1    8.5
2   12
3    6.5
4    7
5    3
6   17.5
7   13
8    8.5
9    6
10  11
11   5
12  10
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Tufte-style bar charts are also easy to do in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).  Since plain Metapost is designed for drawing, and makes no assumptions about how to do charts, you get full control over where your "data ink" goes; but you do have to program everything from scratch.  For something as simple as this sample chart (taken from [*The Visual Display of Quantitative Information*](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) ), the programming effort is minimal, but one should be wary of re-programming the whole of `pgfplots` for more complicated charts.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
% units (measured from my copy of VDQI, p.128)
u = 6cm/23;
v = 2.3mm;

% nice Tufte-like colour (although he uses grey in the original)
color olive; olive = (.7,.7,.55);

% draw the bars
x = 0;
hmax = 0;
for h=8.5,12,6.5,7,3,17.5,13,8.5,6,11,5,10:
  fill unitsquare xscaled u yscaled (v*h) shifted (x,0) withcolor olive;
  x := x+2u;
  if h>hmax: hmax:=h; fi
endfor

% draw and label the grid
for i=5 step 5 until hmax:
  draw (origin -- (23u,0)) shifted (0,i*v) withcolor background;
  label.lft((decimal i & "%") infont "pplr8r" scaled 0.7, (-3/4u,i*v));
endfor

% "Still, a thin baseline looks good:"
linecap := butt;
draw (origin -- (23u,0)) withcolor olive withpen pensquare scaled 0.8;
endfig;
end.
```

If you were doing lots of charts, you could consider writing a more general function to create them.